# MongoDB kubernetes local storage two nodes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, local-storage, local

I am using kubeadm localy at two physical machines. I don't have any cloud resources, and i want to build a mongodb auto scaling (localy for start, maybe later at cloud). So i have to use the local storage of my two physical machines. I suppose i have to create a local storage class and volumes. I am very new to kubernetes so dont judge me hard. As i read here https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/ local persisent volumes are only for one node? Is there any way to take advance of my both physical machines storages and build a simple mongo db scaling, using kubernetes mongo operator and ops manager? I made a few tests here, but i could achieve my goal. [pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims ops manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677594/pod-has-unbound-immediate-persistentvolumeclaims-ops-manager)
What i was thinking in first place, was to "break" my two hard drives into many piecies, and use sharding for mongo dv scaling
thanks in advace.

Comment: What do you think of use a NFS server as commom storage for your mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a NFS Server with the same volume mounted in both nodes sharing the same mount point.

> Please be aware this approach **is not recommended** for production.

There are tons of howtos of how configure nfs server, example:

https://www.tecmint.com/install-nfs-server-on-ubuntu/
https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/

With NFS working you can use the `hostPath` to mount the nfs in you  pods:

Create the PV and the PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/nfs/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

And use the volume in your deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-pv
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pv
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pv
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: pv-storage
      volumes:
        - name: pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-claim
```